# Removing previously added class on page load in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a Table td consisting status field value 1 and 0, if status is 1 I have to add 'ok' Class if it is 0 I have to add 'remove' class by using ajax. I have done that using ajax. But the problem is when I refresh the page after changing status the previous status is adding to all 'td' elements and removing previously added class on page load. I have to show individual current td status on page load.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$this = $('.status-icon');
if($this.hasClass('glyphicon-ok-circle')){
$this.addClass('glyphicon-ok-circle');
}else{
$this.addClass('glyphicon-remove-circle');  
}
$('.status-icon').click(function(){
    $statusClass = $(this);
    $.ajax({
          url : 'router/status-router/',
          data : "id="+$(this).attr('status-id'),
          success: function(data) {
              if(data!=1){
              $statusClass.removeClass('glyphicon-ok-circle').addClass('glyphicon-remove-circle');
              }else{
              $statusClass.removeClass('glyphicon-remove-circle').addClass('glyphicon-ok-circle');
              }

            },
          error : function() {
          }
       });
     });
   });
```

**HTML**

```
<td><a href="#" status-id="<%=$b->getId();%>" class="glyphicon status-icon"></a></td>
```

Comment: Initially i have to add ok class for that added it on .ready() function

Comment: Can we see your html

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: Why would you add a class that's already present? `if($this.hasClass('glyphicon-ok-circle')){
$this.addClass('glyphicon-ok-circle');
}`

Comment: I have tried if for not to remove previously added class. But didn't get it

Comment: I am not sure I understood your issue. If a `td` starts with value 0 and you change to 1, when you refresh the page is value is 0 again, right? And this happens to all `td`, everytime you refesh the page they are at their starting value..?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the current values that are on the page when the page refreshes?  If so, why not call your ajax routine on page load?

Comment: can you provide a live example?